# How to reference a variable in second function in the same class?

Tags: python, function, class, variables, instance-variables

How do I correctly define and call these functions?

I am trying to build an application that will prompt the main menu, go through a `logon` process, go to the next function, which would be the `login menu` and reference the inputs from the `logon` function so users do not have to input their **card number and pin twice**.

The issue I'm having is trying to be able to reference a variable in my second function, which is located in the same class. *I'm being told by coworkers that using globals is bad and I shouldn't*. Here is the code.

I've taken out some things as they aren't really important. I'd like to, for instance, use the `elif choice ==3` statement to reference the original `one_row`.

p.s. I have changed `def Login(self)` to include the variables I'd like to reference, but then my main menu complains that the inputs have not been defined yet.

```
class LoginPrompt:
    def Login(self):
        while True:
            print(menu[1])
            self.Card_number=str(input('>>  '))
            print(menu[2])
            self.Character_PINs = getpass.getpass('>>  ')
            self.one_row = c.execute('SELECT * FROM {tn} WHERE {cn}=? and {cnn}=?'.\
                            format(tn=table_1, cn=column_1, cnn=column_3),    (self.Character_PINs, self.Card_number,))
        for row in self.one_row.fetchone():
                print('Welcome: ', row)
                return

        else:
            print('PIN incorrect; try again')

    def loginMenu(self):
        while True:
            print(menu[5])
            print("\n1 - Deposit funds")
            print("2 - Withdraw funds")
            print("3 - Check balance")
            print("4 - Reset Pin")
            print("5 - Exit")

            while True:
                try:
                    choice = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
                except ValueError:
                    print("This is not a number")
                if choice >= 1 and choice <=5:
                    if choice == 1:
                        amount = input("\nPlease enter the deposit amount: ")
                        if amount != '' and amount.isdigit():
                            int(amount)
                            amount = c.execute('UPDATE {tn} SET Balances = ? WHERE {cn}=?'.\
                                                format(tn=table_1, cn=column_2), (amount,))
                        else:
                            print("Please enter a valid number")
                            conn.commit()
                            conn.close

                    elif choice ==3:
                        print(Login.one_row)

                    elif choice ==5:
                        input('Enjoy your stay, and always remember to drink Nuka Cola! ')
                        return(mainMenu)
                else:
                    return


def mainMenu():
        print(menu[0])
        chosen=False
        while not chosen:
        opt=int(input('\n Please choose one of the options below:\n\n-> Register for a new account [1]\n-> Login to an existing account [2]\n\nPlease type a number...\n\n>>  '))
        if opt==1:
            userReg()
            chosen=True
        elif opt==2:
            login_Menu = LoginPrompt()
            login_Menu.Login()
            chosen=True
            login_Menu.loginMenu()
        else:
            print('\n\nPLEASE TYPE EITHER 1 OR 2...\n ')
    print(chosen)
if __name__ == "__main__":
        while True:
            mainMenu()
```

Comment: `Login.one_row` → `self.one_row`

Comment: so...because it's it's in the same class, you can still use self? I was under the impression it only was used when in the same function. Thank you.

Comment: Because it's in the same *instance*. I've posted a more complete answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you instantiated a single instance of `LoginPrompt` and called `Login` and `loginMenu` on it:

```py
login_Menu = LoginPrompt()
login_Menu.Login()
...
login_Menu.loginMenu()
```

Since you assign an instance variable `self.one_row` in `Login`, you can access the same instance variable via `self.one_row` in `loginMenu`:

```py
class LoginPrompt:
    def Login(self):
        while True:
            ...
            self.one_row = ...
        ...

    def loginMenu(self):
        while True:
            ...

            while True:
                ...
                if choice >= 1 and choice <=5:
                    ...

                    elif choice == 3:
                        # print(Login.one_row)
                        print(self.one_row)
```

You can read more about `self` and instance variables in the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

## A note about code style

In Python, the convention is to:

- name functions consistently in *lower_case_with_underscores* (and classes in *CapWords*), and
- name instances after the class name.

```py
login_prompt = LoginPrompt()
login_prompt.login()
...
login_prompt.login_menu()
```

You can read more about naming conventions in the PEP 8 style guide for Python code: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions

Comment: Is `def loginMenu(self):` indented under `class LoginPrompt:` in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, the website had me reindenting everything all over the place.

Comment: You can use code fences to avoid reindenting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code